# Многоязычный сайт

Tags: jquery, javascript

Ребят подскажите плагин для перевода текста на сайте, нужно что-то вроде этого, но бесплатно
http://www.surstudio.net/translator-lite/samples/sample-1.html

Просмотрел много библиотек, но во всех практически нужно иметь готовые словари. Необходимо, чтобы при выборе языка сайт тянул текст из словаря уже готового, например с гугла или яндекса.
Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

[Вот тут то, что Вас интересует](http://adminway.ru/avtomaticheskii-perevod-vashego-saita-s-pomoshchyu-js-skripta-google-translate)